# How to get list of vnodes

Tags: cnosdb

I want to migrate some vnode nodes to other nodes, but I don't know which vnodes are in the current instance and how should I get them?

I only see the following commands, but not the command to get all vnode:

```
MOVE VNODE
COPY VNODE
DROP VNODE
COMPACT VNODE
```